# What does following javascript code structure mean?

Tags: javascript

I have come across javascript code with following structure.

```
var somevar = function(){
    return {
        init: function(){
            function a(){} // no terminator in between functions.
            function b(){}
            function c(){} and so on
            ...
            some jquery declarations
            ...
        } // init ends
    }; // return ends
}(); // somevar ends
```

Questions are
1. What does this concept is called?
2. How do I call functions inside init function?

**UPDATE** : 
Hope `close` voters understand an importance of this question.

Comment: 1 - javascript, 2 - by calling init

Comment: Is this call onetime only? If I want to call function c separately how would I do that? What does init returns?

Comment: `What does init returns?` - you haven't shown what it returns

Comment: how useful is this function?

Comment: `how useful is this functions?` - as written in the question - pointless, in star trek terms, GNDN (goes nowhere, does nothing)

Comment: okay, thanks Jaromanda.

Comment: don't get me wrong - I can only judge by what you've asked, it's extremely general and I can't make comment on the usefulness of it - the specific question about calling function c is easy, you can't call it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure you are referring to is known as the module pattern.

see [module patterns in depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

Comment: This blog explain the concept(IIFE) in details.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `somevar` contains the responded `object` of a directly executed anonymous function, called [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). The object has one property, `init`, what contains a anonymous function too.

The functions inside the `init` function can only be used on the inside of the anonymous function (*scope*).

```js
var somevar = function() {
    return {
        init: function() {
            // 'a()' is only available inside of the 'init' function
            function a() {
                console.log("init");
            }
            
            a();
        }
    };
}(); // <-- here the outer function is executed directly

// the call of 'init'
somevar.init();
```

Comment: If I want to call function c separately how would I do that?

Comment: you can't do that

Comment: If it is not returned somehow by `init` you simply can't access `c()`. @KishorPawar